# UITableView returns blank cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a table view with height of cells set to automatic. 
Once in a few runs, a few cells in the table are displayed empty (white space). Upon debugging, I noticed that the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' function returns these cells as usual. Also, every time this bug shows up, the console has this message: 
"Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead."

Scrolling up and down a couple of times fixes the issue and cells are displayed.

I use this following functions for height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

[image]

I have been stuck with this for a week and any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: Code for the cells:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var row = indexPath.row

    tableView.allowsSelection = false;

    let cellIdentifier = "testTableViewCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! testTableViewCell

    let post: PostMdl!

    if(row < posts.count) {

        post = posts[row]

    }
    else {
        return cell
    }

    cell.label.delegate = self

    cell.label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue

    cell.label.userInteractionEnabled = true

    cell.brandName.text = post.brandName

    cell.timeStamp.text = post.timeStamp

    cell.brandImg.sd_setImageWithURL(post.brandImgUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeHolder"))


    if let img = post.postImg {
        cell.mainImg.image = img

    } else {

        cell.mainImg.image = UIImage(named:"lazyLoad")

    }

    cell.label.text = post.postTag

    cell.labelDistanceFromImg.constant = 30

    cell.labelDistanceToBtm.constant = 30

    cell.postTag = post.postTag

    cell.socNtwkImg.image = UIImage(named: post.socNtwk)


    return cell
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Remove height from `UITextview` on your prototype cell.Can you update your full table view codes?

Comment: I have only given heights for a couple of images. Other than that its all relative constraints. I have added the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and 'numberOfRowsInSection' in the question. Anything else I should add?

Comment: Try add a container view to cell.contentView, put other label and image view into this container view, and set the container's constraints as my answer. If this suggest can't help you, you can try to calculate cell's height manually and dynamically.

Comment: I cant fix the cell height as it varies with the height of the image. I found the fix though. I had to add 'cell.layoutSubviews()' before returning the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you had set wrong constraints to subviews of UITableViewCell.contentView.

This image shows what I reproduce your error:
[image]

Please note the right constaints of red view, it just has *Top Left Right Height*, lacks bottom constraint, when I add it and it looks good:

[image]

Yes, there still have problem that **Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints**, **we can modify the priority of height constraint, default priority is required(1000), we change to Hight(750)**, it works!

[image]
[image]

I don't know your cell's detail, but the error's reason is likely, hope my answer helps you.

**Append codes**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your mobile phone version of the iOS?
In the previous iOS8 version I also encountered similar problems.
My method is as follows:

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Hope can help you

Comment: Its iOS 9.3. So changing the estimatedRowHeight to a fixed value was the fix? Because I tried that too. Didnt work..

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway :)